# Is the following set a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

can't seem to crack this math question and can't find any tips online:

Given a set of vectors of the form $\langle a, b, c, d\rangle$, does this set form a vector space if:

1. $5a - 2b = -2c - 4d$
2. $6a - 4b = -4c + 5d$

I understand that this vector set contains the zero vector $\langle0, 0, 0, 0\rangle$ and is closed under scalar multiplication. From my calculations, the set also appears to be closed under vector addition so I believe it to be a vector space but apparently this is not the case. Anyone have any idea why this might be so

Comment: Over which field?

Comment: You should consider rewording the question. A single vector $\langle a,b,c,d \rangle$ cannot form a vector space unless it is the zero vector. However, a **collection** of vectors of the form $\langle a,b,c,d \rangle$, subject to some constraints among $a,b,c,d$, may form a vector space, which is I'm sure what you meant here.

Comment: Done. Any idea why the set shown above does not form a vector space?

Comment: Why do you think that "apparently this is not" a vector space?

Comment: The field is R and apparently this set does not form a vector space. I understand it to be closed under addition and scalar multiplication so I'm not sure why this is so

Comment: why is this  apparently?

Comment: It is a vector space. Specifically, it's the intersection of the orthogonal complements of (5,-2,2,4) and (6,-4,4,-5). Are you getting this exercise from a source that says it's not a subspace? If so, then either the exercise is wrong or you have misstated the exercise.

Comment: @SquirtleSquad Doesn't matter. (To rephrase my previous comment over an arbitrary field, it's the intersection of the kernels of the dual maps associated to the two vectors in my previous comment.)

Answer (score 0):

The set of vectors $\langle a, b, c, d\rangle$ is the vectorspace $\mathbb{R}^4$ over $\mathbb{R}$. A subset of a vectorspace that
is closed under scalar multiplication and  closed under vector addition is a vectorspace. So if your subset is closed under scalar multiplication and  closed under vector addition then it is a vectorspace.

Comment: While certainly true, this answer would be improved if you explained **why** the given subset is closed under scalar multiplication and addition.

Comment: @Bungo The OP told us that he already showed this.

Comment: True, but I assume that the question would not have been posted if the OP was confident that his/her work was correct. :-)

Comment: @Bungo I made it community wiki. Feel free to improve the answer.